# Creating Dynamic combobox in multiple front-end Django 1.4 and jQuery?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-1.4, frontend

sorry if you do not understand the translation but I need help with Django 1.4, the fact is that I need an example or a tutorial how to create multiple dynamic backend comboboxes in html form, the combobox data are obtained from the database and should be saved.

An example http://www.martiniglesias.eu/demos/combobox/index.php

The idea of this example is using **Django 1.4, Mysql and Jquery.**

Any question, if not let me know please understand, I will be attentive to your feedback.

Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dajaxproject to get data for dynamic combobox, here is an example: http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/